# Ironpython query

Tags: c#, python, reference, ironpython, setup-project

I have a setup file ready with all the references I need to run the python classes. However, as I do not know much python, I would like to use C# to be able to improve this program as part of my thesis study. I was told IronPython is a wrapper class that can be used to invoke methods on behalf of python using .NET.

how exactly should I go about doing this? does anyone have any code examples? Also do I need to include the references in some path for ironpython to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will be useful: http://www.ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/

Comment: thanks for your reply. However, I want examples in C# ideally. That is,                 `var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
                var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
                paths.Add("c:\\Python26\\lib");
                paths.Add("c:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages");

                paths.Add("C:\\IronPython-2.7\\Lib");`

However, even though I am using these libraries in the search path, it is still giving me 'no fnctl module found'. in the paths i have included all the references for the project in python

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use Ironpython?  Do you have C# Dll's you want to access from scripts?  Or are you planning to allow scripting from your C# app?  You can write in Ironpython and compile to an exe.  Can you provide more detail as to why you are writing a mixed code app?

Comment: I am not even sure if I should opt for IronPython. What I want to do is this. I have classes in python with all the module references inside the same folder ready. Now I want to call these methods from C#

Comment: OK so existing cpython code that you want to access from C#. First Step:  Does you code run correctly in the ironpython interpreter or command line?  There are slight differences between Iron and C Python.  Work those out first.  Then look at the examples for hosting ironpython from C#.